# Custom search bar with rounded corner xamarin forms android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

**Custom searchBar renderer with Rounded corner : iOS**

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged(e);

                var searchbar = (UISearchBar)Control;                
                if (e.NewElement != null)
                {                    
                    searchbar.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;
                    searchbar.Layer.BorderWidth =14;
                    searchbar.Layer.BorderColor =  UIColor.FromRGB(240,240,240).CGColor;
                }
            }
```

**Custom SearchBar renderer : Android ?**

I need to do the same as well as i did for ios , customized search bar with rounded corner and other few customizations , for android i didnt get sufficient informations to fix this. Anybody give some instrutions or ideas .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `SearchBarRenderer` subclass assign the Android `SearchView` a custom *shape* drawable:

```
class CustomSearchBar : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control != null)
            Control.Background = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Forms.Context, Resource.Drawable.custom_search_view);
    }
}
```

In the drawable, customize it to your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:padding="10dp"
 android:shape="rectangle" >
 <corners android:radius="10dp" /> 
 <solid android:color="#baf4ed" />
  <stroke
    android:width="5.0dp"
    android:color="#800000" />
 </shape>
```

For more info on drawables, review the Android docs:

Re: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape=["rectangle" | "oval" | "line" | "ring"] >
    <corners
        android:radius="integer"
        android:topLeftRadius="integer"
        android:topRightRadius="integer"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="integer"
        android:bottomRightRadius="integer" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="integer"
        android:centerX="float"
        android:centerY="float"
        android:centerColor="integer"
        android:endColor="color"
        android:gradientRadius="integer"
        android:startColor="color"
        android:type=["linear" | "radial" | "sweep"]
        android:useLevel=["true" | "false"] />
    <padding
        android:left="integer"
        android:top="integer"
        android:right="integer"
        android:bottom="integer" />
    <size
        android:width="integer"
        android:height="integer" />
    <solid
        android:color="color" />
    <stroke
        android:width="integer"
        android:color="color"
        android:dashWidth="integer"
        android:dashGap="integer" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Two questions, one (1) the view I'm using is c# so how would you implement this in c# code... two (2). Moving forward, should I be using xaml for all the views instead of the already c# views? Is xaml more of a "standard?"

Comment: or!!! lol, is this saying create  an xml file called "custom_search_view" under resources folder?? thanks!

Comment: Did you create the `custom_search_view` in the drawable folder in the android platform project?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, it is a drawable

Answer (score 5):

Not too sure of your exact requirements, but how about simply surrounding the searchbar with a frame?

```
<Frame Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Black" CornerRadius="15" HeightRequest="30">
   <SearchBar BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
</Frame>
```

[searchbar inside trimmed frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0hia.png)